# Django: TypeError at /1/ context must be a dict rather than QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

this is my first Post on this Site. I am learning Django and Python right now and trying to create a Quiztool. I have hughe problems with creating my views and its hard for me to understand how to refine the data in a Queryset. In my Detail View I am raising this error:

> TypeError at /1/
>
> context must be a dict rather than QuerySet.
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://192.168.188.146:8080/1/
>   Django Version:   2.0.1 Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:
>
> context must be a dict rather than QuerySet.
>
> Exception Location:
>     /home/flo/Django2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py
>   in make_context, line 274 Python Executable:
>     /home/flo/Django2.0/bin/python Python Version:  3.5.3 Python Path:
>
> ['/home/flo/Django2.0/quiztool', 
>   '/home/flo/Django2.0/lib/python35.zip', 
>   '/home/flo/Django2.0/lib/python3.5', 
>   '/home/flo/Django2.0/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/home/flo/Django2.0/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5',  '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/home/flo/Django2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
>
> Server time:  Thu, 1 Mar 2018 11:00:35 +0000

I know I have to put the Queryset into a Dictonary but i dont know how to do this.

Here is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    latest_survey_list = Survey.objects.order_by('survey_id')[:5]

    context = {
        'latest_survey_list': latest_survey_list
    }
    return render(request, 'fragen/index.html', context)

def detail(request, survey_id):

    question = Survey.objects.get(pk=survey_id).question.all().values()
    question_dict = {
        'question': question
    }

    return render(request, 'fragen/detail.html', question)
```

And here the detail.html:

```
{% if question %}
    <ul>
    {% for x in question %}
    <li>{{ x.question_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No questions are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

If u need further informations to help me just ask.

Many thanks in advance and my
Regards flotzen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning `question` rather then the dic `question_dict` in here:

```
return render(request, 'fragen/detail.html', question)
```

it should be

```
return render(request, 'fragen/detail.html', question_dict)
```

Comment: wow this is really an easy solution... now i am feeling stupid... many thanks =)

Comment: No problem, we sometimes overlook the simplest things :)

Answer (score 0):

Put everything you need to be in your template in your "question_dict" dict
and then via render like this:

```
return render(request, 'fragen/detail.html', context=question_dict)
```